# CSS - Sidebar not fullsized in scaled mode

Tags: css, scroll, fullscreen, background-color, sidebar

I have an issue with my sidebar. I want it to always be its full size. And if my browser window is too small, it should allow me to scroll down without losing its background color. If you look at the images below, you will see the background doesnt work when I scroll down.

Fullscreen:

[image]

Scaled/Windowed mode:

[image]

This is the css for my sidepanel.

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #1C252E;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 240px;
}
```

I tried putting it inside a wrapper, and making body & html to height (& also tested min-height) 100%, but that did not work.

Html:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <!-- User avatar/message/notification/settings buttons -->
    <div class="userpanel">
        <div class="userpanel-image">
            <img src="image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="userpanel-buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- My Money -->
    <div class="sidebar-top">
        <div class="sidebar-title">
            First Title
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Earnings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> Referrals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Sponsorships</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Earn More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- My Content -->
    <div class="sidebar-middle">
        <div class="sidebar-title">
            Second Title
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Earnings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> Referrals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Sponsorships</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Earn More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Connect -->
    <div class="sidebar-bottom">
        <div class="sidebar-title">
            Third Title
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Earnings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> Referrals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Sponsorships</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Earn More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your html as well.

Comment: @theblindprophet Updated first post

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done (multiple ways to do this):

se this CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #1C252E;
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8zf7fg87/2/

Comment: Now it removed all background color on top and bottom of the sidepanel.

Comment: Check my CSS now. I tried the padding: 10px 0px; it didn't work. I updated the CSS now, and now it kind of works. It works if I set a value in pixels. But I want it to be 100%. https://jsfiddle.net/kcahpvwh/2/

Comment: That was my fault, I was missing something, check out the edited answer and the new fiddle

Comment: Works for me, sorry. My implementation has the side bar at 100% min-height and it expands if it is larger than that. Comment if you have any more questions.